# In LoL, what is the (greek?) symbol on Inferno Nasus amulet?

Tags: league-of-legends

In League of Legends, the Inferno Nasus character has a necklace with three symbols on it. One of the symbols is an Omega, but I don't know what the other two are. Does anyone recognize them?

I'm particularly curious about the second one, since that triangular symbol looks *very* familiar. Do any companies use that as a logo?

[image]

My best guess is that it's a [Sierpinski Triangle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_triangle), the kind where the three triangles overlap as seen on [this page](http://ecademy.agnesscott.edu/~lriddle/ifs/siertri/sierfat.htm), but with two of the three internal lines removed.

Alternatively, some of the symbols for the four classical greek elements look similar - but the lines are in the wrong place and continue outside of the triangle.

Does anyone recognize the triangular symbol with the line through it?

Comment: I am curious why this has any downvotes. I can certainly see it not getting upvoted as it is question that may not be particularly helpful in the future, but it isn't a bad question.

Comment: @Reafexus Arguably, it's about developer intent as to where they got the idea, it might also be inquiring about what the meaning of those symbols is, and it's asking for very miniscule trivia. "Not useful for the site" is a very valid reason to downvote.

Comment: @FEichinger Ah, my mistake! I more frequently visit Stack Overflow rather than the gaming site, so I thought this was general game appreciation and gaming questions (art styles, gaming music, gaming plot, game characters, game theories, etc...), not merely *gameplay*-focused questions. I should've read the FAQ first. If this question is truly offtopic here, vote to close it!

Comment: Upon reading the [FAQ](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and the [Asking guidelines](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) it appears that my question *is* ontopic afterall, because it has a definite answer (though my question should be more clearly, "*What is this symbol?*" and not "*Do any companies use that logo?*"), and the site *is* more than just gameplay, including things like "*Plot and characters in games*", and *other* non-gameplay related questions (the [on-topic list](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) isn't exhaustive, just representative).

Comment: On-topicness has nothing to do with downvotes. Downvotes are purely a measure of quality and usefulness of a question. As a matter of fact, this question hasn't gotten a single close vote.

Comment: The triangle looks a bit like the adidas logo ;)

Answer (score 4):

All of these *could be* variations of Greek letters (in particular: Ω Omega, Δ Delta, Θ Theta / Ο Omicron).

Quite possibly an inspiration for the design (with [Nasus's background](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Nasus/Background) placing Nasus in what is roughly the [equivalent of Ancient Egypt](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Shurima_Desert)) are *[Egyptian hieroglyphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egyptian_hieroglyphs)*. Vertically aligned symbols and the use of underbars and simple shapes on a well-defined base (the individual blocks on the chain) is common there.

That said, these symbols don't match any commonly used characters or symbols, and barring any developer word we cannot - and should not - speculate on their meaning or actual origin.

The underlined Omega could be found in the [Omega watchmaker's logo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omega_SA), the Delta might match the [TYPO3 logo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TYPO3), and the underlined Omicron with a bold dot inside could be an eye, as used in [various logos and logo concepts](https://www.google.com/search?q=eye+logo&tbm=isch). The simplicity of these shapes makes them very common abstractions of existing logos, but the shapes themselves are generally not the actual logo.

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely that these are just stylized sings of the zodiac, with the triangles as stylized elemental signs in between.

I think the first sign is the zodiac symbol for [Libra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libra_%28astrology%29), and the third one is the symbol for Sol, or the Sun, which is often characterized as a dot within a circle - the underline is probably flair.

The triangles might be signs for [Earth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_%28classical_element%29) and [Air](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_%28classical_element%29), although again stylized by the fact they are rotated by 120 degrees.

Libra, from Wikipedia:

[image: Libra, from Wikipedia]

Sun, from Wikipedia:

[image: Sun, from Wikipedia]

Earth, from Wikipedia:

[image: Earth, from Wikipedia]

Air, from Wikipedia:

[image: Air, from Wikipedia]

Comment: I'm not entirely convinced about Earth and Air. Those symbols are cut-off, turning the triangle into a triangle and a trapezoid, while the amulet features triangles that are merely extended into a larger triangle on one side.

Comment: I have seen other representations of Earth and Air, where the line does not extend outside of the triangle - I just used the Wiki ones as an example.